# how to add static property in XSD file

Tags: xsd

I have one Java interface for example as following
public interface A

```
 public static final String SD_A= "SD-A";
```

My question is how write the above property in XSD file ? Because I have blaze advisor project where I used XML BOM getting error that-  A is not defined in current scope. So when I am adding that interface as following
I am getting error like :- is not a constant or static property defined by 'A'

Any suggestion to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to add a static field to your schema-derived classes.

The simplest thing you can do is to use the code injector plugin:

```
Inserting code with XJC+xsd+jxb using the options " -Xinject-code -extension "
```

Something like:

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
     <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='SomeExtension']">
        <ci:code>
        public static final String EXTENSION_CODE = "NAMEOFTHEEXTENSION";
        </ci:code>
     </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: <xs:complexType name="IClassProducts">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="AHS" type="static" fixed="AHS" />
     
     
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
I want to do as above in XSD file becuse I am using only xsd file so where I will use <jxb:bindings> in xsd file ?

Comment: I didn't get your question, explain more

Comment: I have created XSD file through eclipse i.e File->New->Other->JAXB->Scema from JAXB Classes

Comment: I have by mistake added my comment in Answer section. can you please go through it ?

Comment: here in my case I have to generate XSD from  Java interface

Comment: should I add the following code in XSD file?
  <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='SomeExtension']">
        <ci:code>
        public static final String EXTENSION_CODE = "NAMEOFTHEEXTENSION";
        </ci:code>
     </jxb:bindings>

Answer (score 0):

I have created XSD file through eclipse i.e File->New->Other->JAXB->Scema from JAXB Classes
from Java application of Java classes. But now I required to make a XSD of Java interface. so when I am following the above process to create a XSD it is showing error "
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.test.IClassproduct is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.

So I have added that interface in another XSD file as below format

```
<xs:complexType name="IClassProducts"> <xs:sequence> <xs:element name="AHS" type="static" fixed="AHS" /> </xs:sequence> </xs:complexType>
```

But now it is showing error

'AHS' is not a constant or static property defined by 'IClassProducts'

so you have suggested to use below format .

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
     <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='SomeExtension']">
        <ci:code>
        public static final String EXTENSION_CODE = "NAMEOFTHEEXTENSION";
        </ci:code>
     </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

My question is where I will add this and how to use . My purpose is anyhow I have use the above static property 'AHS' in XSD file So that when I will load that XSD file it can identify that property and can resolve the below error
'AHS' is not a constant or static property defined by 'IClassProducts'

Comment: should I add the following code in XSD file?
  <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='SomeExtension']">
        <ci:code>
        public static final String EXTENSION_CODE = "NAMEOFTHEEXTENSION";
        </ci:code>
     </jxb:bindings>